# How I can do vertically center alignment in TEXTAREA in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to do vertically center alignment of text in TEXT-AREA. Please suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

**There are two ways to do it**

1. Direct positioning the textarea

   `<textarea style="height: 300px; width: 400px;; top:50%; margin-top: -150px; position: absolute;">
   </textarea>`
2. Use table property in element style

   ```
   <div style=" display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; height: 300px; width: 400px;">
       <textarea style="height: 200px; width: 500px; display: table-cell;"></textarea>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but it put my TextArea field on the center of Form, I want to put text center in the TextArea field.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that you have to use  any api for it like elastic.js. While using this api add  padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;  instead of height and width in style attribute of textarea tag

Answer (score -1):

[Click this example of Vertical Middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUpLu.gif)

This may be what you are looking for.  Straight HTML.  Click the image above.

```
<table width="40%" height="200">
    <td height="150" valign="middle">
    <font size="3" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
        Yay,  I am in the Vertical Middle!!!!!
    </font>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: That's not a `<textarea>` element.

Comment: This might work but is not the right way to do it: it uses table markup while the content to be displayed is not something that would regularly be described as a table-kind of data (like a shool timetable e.g.). Furthermore Vikas asked for a textarea solution. Don't use attributes like face, valign, width, height, etc. Use css style instead (that is if you are not building an email template).